# PHP explode array foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i try to foreach on array that comes from explode()

i have this:

```
     $links = " http://hi.co.il<br>
        ht tp://hi.co.il<br>
   http://hi.co.il<br>
   http://hi.co.il<br>
   http://hi.co.il<br>
   http://mega.co.il<br>
   http://hi.co.il";

   $links = explode('<br>',trim($links));
   //$links = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $links);
   $currenturl = "http://mega.co.il";

   //if(($key = array_search($currenturl, $links)) !== false) {
  //  unset($links[$key]);
//}

    foreach($links as $key => $value):

     if($value == $currenturl):
         unset($links[$key]);
     endif;

    endforeach;

   print_r($links);
```

$links printed before foreach:

```
Array ( [0] => http://hi.co.il [1] => ht tp://hi.co.il [2] => http://hi.co.il [3] => http://hi.co.il [4] => http://hi.co.il [5] => http://mega.co.il [6] => http://hi.co.il )
```

$links printed after foreach:

```
http://hi.co.il ht tp://hi.co.il http://hi.co.il http://hi.co.il http://hi.co.il http://mega.co.il http://hi.co.il
```

why foreach take out from array back to string ?
I want to check with foreach if its current url then unset from array, i am newbie and i can make it to work with array_search but i want to do it with foreach.

Thanks for answers and sorry for bad english.

Comment: [I can't reproduce that issue](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/70650a75b725b007f1cb6f0b1855f98f4e337487). Is it possible for you to help reproduce it?

Comment: If you have the newlines in the original `$links` string, you would want to call `$value = trim($value)` on each iteration of the loop. Else, the newlines would be part of each string and not be an exact match. The initial trim will only remove whitespace from the entire string, not each value in the resulting array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works just fine, nothing is turning the array into a string. You should be trimming your strings afterwards though, for your matching to work.

```
<?php

$links = "http://hi.co.il<br>
http://hi.co.il<br>
http://hi.co.il<br>
http://hi.co.il<br>
http://hi.co.il<br>
http://mega.co.il<br>
http://hi.co.il";

$links = explode('<br>',trim($links));
print_r($links);
$currenturl = "http://mega.co.il";

foreach($links as $key => $value) {
    if(trim($value) == $currenturl) {
        unset($links[$key]);
    }
}
print_r($links);
?>
```

I'd recommend not using [alternate syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for code blocks, these are generally meant for use in HTML templating and will probably get you into trouble.

Comment: I swear that didn't worked for me and then now i take your foreach and this working,thanks dude.

Comment: I would suggest using `===` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$links = array_filter(
  $links,function($element) {
  return $element !== 'http://mega.co.il';
});
```

`array_filter` will remove any element where the return value of the `function` is `false`. For all elements, return value will be `true`, except the one that matches.

And miken32 is right about your `:` and `endif` stuff. Usually that is only used when your PHP code is sprinkled lightly in a mostly-HTML file. For pure PHP code, most people use the curly braces `{` and `}` along with indentation.

Considering JonathanKuhn's comment, you could also try this slight variation:

```
$links = array_filter(
  $links,function($element) {
  return strpos($element,'http://mega.co.il') !== true;
});
```

This will also give you the desired filtering effect, but it will not remove all newlines. To remove the newlines as well, you could do this:

```
array_walk($links,function($value,$key) {
  $value = trim($value);
});
$links = array_filter(
  $links,function($element) {
  return strpos($element,'http://mega.co.il') !== true;
});
```

Comment: thanks for alternate way but i prefer foreach as i need do more things on part of array keys.

Comment: @user2635001 You could also use `array_walk` for applying functions to each element of the array. I read somewhere that unsetting elements inside a `foreach` loop can cause unpredictable results, but I can't find the reference now. For that reason, I would often use a copy of the array in the foreach loop, then copy that array over the original array variable. Also, you should probably upvote miken's answer since you accepted it. ;)